# How to show missing values in table rows and columns?

Tags: user-expectation, tables, grid, data-tables

**Approach 1** Show NA for missing items

[image]

**Approach 2** Show - sign for missing items
[image]

I have a table that displays crypto prices, volume etc. There are often times when I don't have data in a particular column. I tried 2 approaches

1. Show 'NA' for missing items
2. Show '-' for missing items

What is the right way to do this? Thank you for your answers in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have the relevant information? If there aren't any trades the volume is just 0.

Edit: let me explain myself a bit more clear as I did in the comments. You would have to check if you are dealing with financial data why you don't have any value there, since the crypto markets are always open. I see two possibilities, the first being there is a technical error and for some reason you are unable to retrieve the most recent data. The second one is that the API doesn't offer you new data for that time period. I you don't have values for the Volume column, that means that there were no trades so it defaults to zero. Same goes for percentage change etc. I would ask myself WHY you aren't getting any data. It would be useful to include the table headers here.

Comment: There's a difference between Zero and 'no information' though.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question, as it is incorrect. Zero can not be represent missing data as zero is a value, whilst missing information is literally nothing.

Comment: Not exactly true if this is financial data. Some APIs do not provide any data if there was no change, ie if there was no trading volume or the value was unchanged.